# App crashes when adding new data to the viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have created a ViewPager in which i am using bitmapArray to display images in viewpager.Every thing works fine but when i add a new data and call notifydatasetchange,the app crashes.

In this App i am downloading songs and from that file i am fetching the bitmap from that downloaded song and add in the bitmap array.

It gives the following Execption:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I am unable to find what causes this execption

Adapter class for ViewPager is :

```
public class CoverFlowPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmapArray;
    Context c;

    interface CoverFlowClick {
        public void coverClick(int coverFlowPosition);
    }

    CoverFlowClick mCoverFlowClick;

    public CoverFlowPagerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitmapArray) {
        this.c = c;
        this.mBitmapArray = mBitmapArray;
        mCoverFlowClick = (CoverFlowClick) c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mBitmapArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (object == view);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        ImageView imageView;
        View v = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.coverflow_item,null);
        imageView= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.coverFlowImage);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmapArray.get(position));

        container.addView(imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Clicked::--" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mCoverFlowClick.coverClick(position);
            }
        });

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

I am adding the bitmap to array and calling notifydatasetchanged like this:

```
@Override
    public void updateSongList(String songName) {

        getBitmapArray(songName);
        mCoverFlowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

**EDIT:** My custom Layout File is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coverFlowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and my getBitmapArray function is

```
public void getBitmapArray(String songName) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppDownloads/" + songName;
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            metaRetriver.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
        if (art != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        }

        if (bitmap != null) {
            mBitmapArray.add(bitmap);
        } else {
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.unknown_album);
            mBitmapArray.add(icon);
        }
    }
```

Comment: v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.coverflow_item,container, false); try this.

Comment: plz add **getBitmapArray** code

Comment: Check my Edit @RahulSharma

Comment: **updateSongList** is inside your activity or fragment class. right?

Comment: Yes it is in my activity.It is an implemented method which updates when the song download complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making LinearLayout as parent of ImageView, let ImageView be the ROOT of the Layout as follows:-

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coverFlowImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In the adapter:-

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.coverflow_item, container, false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmapArray.get(position));

    container.addView(imageView);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Clicked::--" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCoverFlowClick.coverClick(position);
        }
    });

    return imageView;
}
```

If you want to use a LinearLayout as ROOT then instead of adding ImageView to the **container**, add the **inflated view** and also return it in the **instantiateItem** method.

Also change **destroyItem** method to

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your custom layout file `coverflow_item.xml` contains `ImageView` already.

Again you'r trying to add in same container using

> container.addView(imageView);

That's why its throwing exception.

To overcome it , you need to change

```
container.addView(imageView);
```

to

```
container.addView(v);
```

and this one also

```
return imageView;
```

to

```
return v;
```

**EDIT:**

Change this too

```
container.removeView((ImageView) object);
```

to

```
container.removeView((LinearLayout)object)
```

Comment: Its crashing again

Comment: Call `container.removeAllViews()` before this line         `container.addView(imageView);` and after that use my answer.

Comment: Its again crash

Comment: container.removeAllViews() This line in adapter

Comment: Did u try my answer? After using my answer what error throwing. Comment this  
container.removeAllViews()

Comment: Yes i did both by adding and trying your answer,In both cases the application crashes

Comment: Show me your custom row item file. And does it contain _ImageView_ as a parent layout?

Comment: U should change this _container.removeView((ImageView) object);_ to                  _container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);_ and then use my answer

Comment: @AbhayBohra Updated my answer

Comment: It worked when i made ImageView as parent layout.Your solutions made my concept more clear.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

look here :

```
   imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmapArray.get(position));
    container.addView(imageView);
```

every time you are adding biotmap it is adding it to same container now how can a container holding one view can add other over it so   you need to remove older view: somthing like this

```
  @Override
public void updateSongList(String songName) {

    getBitmapArray(songName);
    container.removeView((ImageView) object)
    mCoverFlowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

PS: code for illustration please make sure u passing correct params
Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently implemented this and this is my instantiateItem method (made it a bit minimal for readability.

```
 @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

     Evaluation evaluation = evaluations.get(position); 

     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_evaluation, null);

     TextView evaluationSummary = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.evaluation_summary);

     evaluationSummary.setText(evaluation.getEvaluationSummary());

     ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);

   return layout;
}

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
   return view == object;
}
```

So for the page that is displayed, I get the data from my evaluations list using the position as the index. Then inflate the Layout which has the views I will add my data too. Then I get the TextView to set the evaluation summary text on. Then the whole Layout is added to the ViewPager. And finally the Layout is also returned.

let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Its giving me the same execption

Comment: try to add container.addView(imageView); and return to the v

Comment: Actually i am not using fragment..In my activity i am implementing a listner that gives the downloaded song and from that i am getting bitmap and adding it to bitmap array using getBitmapArray(songName)

Comment: @AbhayBohra Did u check my answer

Comment: try to create dynamically created imageView.

Comment: try to check @Piyush answer, It's once also correct way

Comment: Okay don't worry... be happy.... try to dowanload souce code here : https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow. please check it and let me know

Comment: @AbhayBohra Read my comment

Comment: @ManikandanK ok i will try this and tell you